# The import cannot be resolved in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

Though I have all my source in proper packages.It couldn't find at the time of Building Project.Normally it shows links everything.But at the time of Build Project or Autobuild while directly running project.

```
The import ecnet.rd.config cannot be resolved
```

like it shows for all the internal imports.But external imports like imports from JAR files are working.

**P.S :**

My Eclipse  latestly crashed but it was working well after that, Once again this kind of things are happening.

Please help to find the way to solve this.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

In my experience, it is usual with Eclipse to have the build messed up. Make sure `Build automatically` is checked and `Clean`. If it doesn't work, restart Eclipse and do again.

Also as Tech Junkie comments below, try also `Clean all projects`.

Comment: it will be helpful for newbies......

Comment: worked when I said, 'Clean all projects'

Comment: ++ for @TechJunkie's comment - worked for me, whereas cleaning the problematic project alone didn't (for some odd reason).

Comment: @TechJunkie Where can I find this "Clean all projects" menu?

Comment: clean build and build automatically both not working for me

Comment: @BikashGyawali Project -> Clean... -> Check the checkbox "Clean all projects", click "Clean"

Comment: I solved a local "import cannot be resolved" issue by renaming the file I was importing, and then naming it again to what it was originally. For example "TestService.java" -> "TestServiceNew.java" -> "TestService.java"

Answer (score 19):

I've seen this happen and another approach to take which is similar to m0skit0 solution (if you are using Eclipse) is to `right click` on the project, select `maven`, select `update project`, make sure `clean projects` and `refresh workspace` are checked, and hit `ok`.

Answer (score 4):

After hours of struggle, creating a new Eclipse workspace, reimporting the projects and resetting up the same tomcat instance worked.

Probably the eclipse settings got messed up, and the deploy wasn't being done correctly anymore.

Comment: Actually, I had to delete the existing project and then import again the project