# How to import lib to android eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse-plugin, spell-checking

I'm new to android.Here i create an application for spell checker.I got an error that one header file can not be resolved.in my android.jar file the lib are missing.How to download this lib and import to my project.

```
 import android.view.textservice.SentenceSuggestionsInfo;
```

[image: i got this error window]

Comment: Try this answer [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21527653/the-import-cannot-be-resolved-in-eclipse](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21527653/the-import-cannot-be-resolved-in-eclipse)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add a Library Project to a android project?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8248196/how-to-add-a-library-project-to-a-android-project)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

U can make Library folder in your project..and can add required lib in that library folder.. check the image.. hope it make sense.

[image]