# The method extractAll(String) is undefined for the type ZipFile with zip4j

Tags: java, xml, parsing, bigdata, zip4j

I'm trying to make a program which unzips then parses the xml file in xml.zip.
Adding the dependency for zip4j, this is my pom.xml

```
        <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>interview</groupId>
    <artifactId>programES</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>xmlToES</name>
    <dependencies>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat/jackson-dataformat-xml -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-xml</artifactId>
            <version>2.12.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-lang3 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>3.11</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-databind -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.12.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.lingala.zip4j/zip4j -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.lingala.zip4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>zip4j</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.4</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
</project>
```

My code for the parser :

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.xml.XmlMapper;

import model.Products;
import net.lingala.zip4j.core.ZipFile;
import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils;
import java.util.zip.ZipFile;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;

public class Parser {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new XmlMapper();
        String source = "C:\\Users\\user\\java_program\\xml.zip";
        String destination = "C:\\Users\\user\\java_program\\xml";
        ZipFile zipFile = new ZipFile(source);
        zipFile.extractAll(destination);
        //Reads from XML and converts to POJO
        Products products = objectMapper.readValue(
                StringUtils.toEncodedString(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("C:\\Users\\user\\java_program\\xml\\xml.xml")), StandardCharsets.UTF_8), Products.class);
        System.out.println(products);
    }

}
```

The program still write an error : The method extractAll(String) is undefined for the type ZipFile

any help is really appreciated

Comment: You code won't even compile due to clashing imports

Comment: I'm using java 15.0.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should import `net.lingala.zip4j.core.ZipFile` instead of `java.util.zip.Zipfile`

delete the line:

```
import java.util.zip.ZipFile;
```

and delete
`.core` from your import `import net.lingala.zip4j.core.ZipFile;`

Whole class:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.xml.XmlMapper;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import model.Products;
import net.lingala.zip4j.ZipFile;
import net.lingala.zip4j.exception.ZipException;
import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils;


public class Parser {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, ZipException {
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new XmlMapper();
        String source = "C:\\Users\\user\\java_program\\xml.zip";
        String destination = "C:\\Users\\user\\java_program\\xml";
        ZipFile zipFile = new ZipFile(source);
        zipFile.extractAll(destination);
        //Reads from XML and converts to POJO
        Products products = objectMapper.readValue(
            StringUtils.toEncodedString(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("C:\\Users\\user\\java_program\\xml\\xml.xml")), StandardCharsets.UTF_8), Products.class);
        System.out.println(products);
    }
}
```

Comment: It's already imported but when I delete it the program write an error ZipFile cannot be resolved to a type now :/

Comment: I copied the whole class.

Comment: Does it work for you ? The problem still appear to me with the errors : "The import net.lingala.zip4j.core cannot be resolved" and "ZipFile cannot be resolved to a type" and probably the problem is related to this topic https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21527653/the-import-cannot-be-resolved-in-eclipse maybe my eclipse settings are messed up :/ please keep me informed

Comment: Can you provide your pom? mvn clean install or reimport can help you, if you added to the pom.xml

Comment: Have you tried to compile it and refresh the whole project?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228367/discussion-between-amamra-and-tomeszmh).

Answer (score 0):

In your imports you are importing java.util.Zipfile so remove -

```
import java.util.zip.ZipFile;
```

and it should work.

Comment: The program write an error ZipFile cannot be resolved to a type now :/

Comment: Does it build from the command line outside of Eclipse?